# program abortion on exit after a multipage TIFF is read into a vector of Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw-w64, msys2

This code does what it is programmed for, but it terminates with abortion:

```
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv){
    vector<Mat> mats;
    imreadmulti( argv[ 1], mats, 0, 1, -1);
    cout << "sz = " << mats.size() << endl; 
}
```

More lines of code can be put before the rightmost curly brace and they are executed as expected, but again the program terminates with abortion.

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o ../bin/main -L/ucrt64/lib $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4); ../bin/main data.tiff
sz = 1
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is the environment I am using:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ uname
MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045

$ echo $MSYSTEM
UCRT64

$ echo $MSYSTEM_CARCH 
x86_64

$ pacman -Qs opencv
local/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-opencv 4.9.0-4
    Open Source Computer Vision Library (mingw-w64)
```

The code shown is what I am arrived at, after trying to isolate the problem. It's clear now that whatever is the problem it is not due to tiff size, since I'm reading just one page of the TIFF. I'm working with a multipage image of 2146 pages of 1MB each. Moreover the last line of code printing on stdout tells that the reading has been performed well. I was even able to imwritemulti into a new file what has just been read.

Comment: so... the program crashes *after `main()` returns*? -- what happens if you read one page of a multi-page tiff that has a lot fewer than 2000 pages (everything else, including resolution, being the same)?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes, after main() returns. The result is the same even for a single page tiff.

Comment: ok so process crashes after main returns, on a single/multi-page tiff read with imreadmulti()... I am inclined to recommend filing a bug (or, if it has been reported already, adding your findings). can you find any single/multi-page tiffs that *don't* crash the process in this manner? can you provide a (preferably small) tiff that the process *does* crash on?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I confirm your first statement. Currently I have not find any tiff file with which the crash does not occur. When you say to provide do you want me to do it for a more complete documentation when filing the bug to the opencv issue tracker or to provide it here, because in this last case I do not know how to post a binary file here. (anyway, yes I have a smaller file of 550kB of 2 pages, on which the crash still occurs)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz bug issue just opened